# how to change simply this moment to find mgf & pdf?

Tags: statistics

[image]

I need to change simply this moment to find mgf & pdf.

i did found that sigma from j1~jn>=1 (k j1,j2...) is like Multinomial distribution thing.
but i don;t know how to change that equation to some simple form.

Please help me  T.T

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. See [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers.

Comment: What is $\binom{-2}l$ here? I would expect $0$ because there are $0$ ways to select $l$ objects out of $-2$ objects.

Comment: @drhab $$\binom{r}{k}=\frac{r(r-1)\cdot\ldots \cdot (r-k+1)}{k!}$$ for arbitrary real $r$ and integer $k\geq 0$. See, for example, R.L.Graham, D.E.Knuth, O.Patashnik Concrete Mathematics, chapter 5.